# Solspace - Primary Category no category

Tags: solspace, categories

Is there a way to display something if there IS NOT a primary category?

We've tried these with no luck:

```
{exp:primary_category entry_id="{segment_2}"}


{if primary_category_id}
YES 
{if:else}
NO
{/if}

{if primary_category_id} YES {/if}<br>

{if primary_category_id == ""} NO {/if}<br>

{/exp:primary_category}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you perhaps do...

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT primary_category_id FROM exp_primary_category WHERE entry_id='{segment_2}'"}
    {embed="site/yes"}
    {if no_results}
        {embed="site/no"}
    {/if}
{/exp:query}
```

Be careful of placing this inside a channel:entries loop though as the {if no_results} tag will be caught by that instead of the query loop.

Not verified but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not available with Primary Category at this time.

Comment: Any way this might be do-able this an embed or some other such logic?